# Tabs don't appear with TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm trying to get a simple `TabLayout` with 3 tabs. Having follow different tutorials, my tab don't show up on the final result ( There is just 3 empty tab with no text ).

This how I try to add those tabs:

First the xml layout container the `ViewPager` (communitylayout)

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomcontent3"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/comtabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/compager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

The `Tab` xml (tabtext):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabtext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally the java class where I try to add those Tabs:

```
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.communitylayout, container, false); // communitylayout is the first xml I put, see above
        Bundle data = getArguments();
        MainActivity.addShapeAndBottom(inflater, view, "com", this);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.comtabs);

        // add tabs
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());

        RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.communitytablayout, container, false);
        RelativeLayout layout2 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.communitytablayout, container, false);
        RelativeLayout layout3 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.communitytablayout, container, false);

            //tab is an array of Strings containing the Tab name  


((TextView)layout1.findViewById(R.id.tabtext)).setText(tabs[0]);
((TextView)layout2.findViewById(R.id.tabtext)).setText(tabs[1]);
((TextView)layout3.findViewById(R.id.tabtext)).setText(tabs[2]);


        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(layout1);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(layout2);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(layout3);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);



        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.compager);
        CommunityPagerFragment adapter = new CommunityPagerFragment(getChildFragmentManager());

        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
        //tabLayout.set

        return view;
```

I'm kind of lost, I don't know why my Tabs remain invisible. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**  Here is my adapter:

```
public class CommunityPagerFragment extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public CommunityPagerFragment(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return new BlogFragment();
            case 1:
                return new NewsFragment();
            case 2:
                return new FAQFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }




    public class BlogFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.communitylistview, container, false);
            return view;
        }
    }

    public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.communitylistview, container, false);
            /*ProgressBar loadingAnim = new ProgressBar(getContext());
            loadingAnim.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(40,40));
            container.addView(loadingAnim);*/

            return view;
        }
    }

    public class FAQFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.communitylistview, container, false);
            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was to `setupWithViewpager` first before managing the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

You aready have a viewpager, why don't you use  setupWithViewPager method?

```
getTabbar().setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Add fragment to adapter

```
BaseFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new BaseFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(new ExampleListedRecyclerViewFragment(), "Tab title 1", false);
adapter.addFragment(new ExampleGridedRecyclerViewFragment(), "Tab title 2", false);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

ViewPager adapter

```
public  class BaseFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public BaseFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        addFragment(fragment, title, true);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title, boolean hasOptionsMenu) {
        fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(hasOptionsMenu);
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

if you want to set an icon to tab item instead of text title:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(iconDrawable);
```

more detials please see my project

https://github.com/DanielShum/MaterialAppBase/blob/master/materialAppBaseLibrary/src/main/java/com/daililol/material/appbase/base/BaseTabbableActionbarActivity.java

https://github.com/DanielShum/MaterialAppBase/

Comment: I have a PageAdapter looking a bit like yours. I'll add it in the main post, maybe my problem comes from here? EDIT: I use setupWithViewPager; the problem is not the content of the TabLayout but the tabs themself, setting the text or using setCustomView doesnt work at all...

Comment: i just read your code, first, you do not have to add tabs while you use setupWithViewpage method, the tablayout will add them for you accroding to the number of your fragments in your viewpager adapter. second, if you don't like the origonal tabs, you want use yout customized tab, you have to do it after setupWithViewpage method. I mean "tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(layout1)" this code should be after the setupWithViewpage method.

Comment: Man, you're awesome! That was it. I had to put my setupWithViewpager before managing the tabs!

Comment: so in return, please make my answer as the correct answer so that i can earn some reputation. thank you!

Comment: I will but add that the solution was to setupWithViewpager before managing the tabs first, so it will help the following. I upvoted you as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Element tab XML where you want:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            ></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

In your MainActivity:

```
TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
```

[image]

Comment: I did! I have basically like you, except that the text on the tabs remain invisible! Changing the background color in tabtext.xml to check if the tab got the layout successfully doesnt work as well...

Answer (score 0):

setupWithViewpager first before managing the tabs.

xml layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`enter code here`
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/coloricon" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

in Fragment :

```
public class myfragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_xml, container, false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = V.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        TabItem tabScan = V.findViewById(R.id.tab1);
        TabItem tabCreate = V.findViewById(R.id.tab2);
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) V.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
//setupWithViewpager first before managing the tabs.

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("1");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText("2");
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        return V;

    }
    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        int mNumOfTabs;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
            super(fm);
            this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new fragment1();
                case 1:
                    return new fragment2();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mNumOfTabs;
        }
    }

}
```